# Updating url on transition from child to parent state in UI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular (1.2.1) app running UI-router (0.2.13), and the following state structure:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        template: "<div home></div>",
        url: '/'
    }).state('home.geo', { 
        url:'/geo/{geo}' 
}
```

Transitioning from parent to child or between children with different `{geo}` parameter values works as expected. Transitioning from child to parent works - i.e. the contents of the template and $state.current change as expected - but the URL does not update in the browser.

To be clear, an example: I'm in `/geo/california` and I click a button with `ui-sref='home'`. I've confirmed that the correct `href='#/'` has been placed on the button, and clicking it causes the $state to transition back to the home state, but `/geo/california` remains in my address bar.

What am I missing here?

**Update** in respose to @UlukBiy's comment: No, `home` does not have a ui-view in its template. The ui-view is in the template of it's parent: The overall structure is:

```
<body> 
   <div app-nav></div>
   <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

So the home directive gets inserted into the ui-view, but it contains no ui-views of its own. Is that my problem? I'm new to UI-router, and assumed  there was some low-level misunderstanding about the role of states vs. directives when I posted this. If so, please help me correct it.

Comment: Has the 'home' state got a 'ui-view' in its template? I tested the similar case and it is working as expected. Imho you need to provide more details.

Comment: Interesting. No it doesn't - please see edit @UlukBiy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario should be working. There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/o6H9KTlVrDNWub7U6x6q?p=preview) *(click the blue button right-top to run example in separate window, showing the address bar)*

I updated your state def a bit:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      template: 'Home view <hr /> Geo view: <div ui-view></div>',
  })
  .state('home.geo', {
      url:'^/geo/{geo}',
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
```

All these links do work as expected:

```
<a href="#/home">
<a href="#/geo/california">
<a href="#/geo/czechia">

<a ui-sref="home">
<a ui-sref="home.geo({geo:'california'})">
<a ui-sref="home.geo({geo:'czech'})">
```

So, the most important change here is that for a child state we should use this url:

```
url:'^/geo/{geo}',
```

instead of the `url:'/geo/{geo}'`. Check the doc:

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol `'^'`.

Check the working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/o6H9KTlVrDNWub7U6x6q?p=preview)